Getting Element Attributes in Dioxus
I was wondering how I could get element attributes in Dioxus in Rust. More specifically, how can I get the element height and width. The CSS uses % instead of px and I want to somehow get the px of the element.
...
div { class: "some_class",
    // get div height here
}
...

Thank you for your help in advance!
I am hoping not to have to use JavaScript, but currently I am not sure what support Dioxus has to offer.

I don't think this is the way that Dioxus works. Can you perhaps explain what kind of program you are trying to write and what you think you need element attribute access for?

I am trying to get the ratio between where the mouse is over the size of the element. The reason I need that is because I am trying to have an interactive element that allows for users to plot points and then scale when the window is made smaller. Thanks.

maybe this helps: https://github.com/DioxusLabs/dioxus/discussions/999

From https://github.com/DioxusLabs/dioxus/blob/main/examples/read_size.rs:
Whenever an Element is finally mounted to the Dom, its data is available to be read.
These fields can typically only be read asynchronously, since various renderers need to release the main thread to
perform layout and painting.
use std::rc::Rc;

use dioxus::{html::geometry::euclid::Rect, prelude::*};

fn main() {
    dioxus::launch(app);
}

fn app() -> Element {
    // Create a mutable signal to store the MountedData of the div element
    let mut div_element = use_signal(|| None as Option<Rc<MountedData>>);
    
    // Create a mutable signal to store the dimensions of the div element
    let mut dimensions = use_signal(Rect::zero);

    // Define an async closure to read the dimensions
    let read_dims = move |_| async move {
        // Read the current value of div_element
        let read = div_element.read();
        
        // Get the client rectangle from the read data
        let client_rect = read.as_ref().map(|el| el.get_client_rect());

        // Check if there's a client rectangle
        if let Some(client_rect) = client_rect {
            // Await the client rectangle
            if let Ok(rect) = client_rect.await {
                // Set the dimensions signal with the received rectangle
                dimensions.set(rect);
            }
        }
    };

    rsx!(
        document::Link { rel: "stylesheet", href: asset!("./examples/assets/read_size.css") }
        div {
            width: "50%",
            height: "50%",
            background_color: "red",
            
            // Set data on mount
            onmounted: move |cx| div_element.set(Some(cx.data())),
            
            // Display the current dimensions of the div
            "This element is {dimensions():?}"
        }

        // Add a button to trigger reading dimensions
        button { onclick: read_dims, "Read dimensions" }
    )
}


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
